# Insert data into big query using php

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to make a small website using google cloud. I am able to host a static page for now. Now, I want  to connect a php page which inserts data(inserted as a login input on my front end) into big query of google-cloud. How do I do it?

P.S. I am very new to google cloud. I am not able to understand its documentation.

For anymore required references, please do mention it.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api#bigquery-simple-app-print-result-python) is quite a good starting point. You have to use the [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) in order to insert data into a table in BigQuery. You may want to have a look to in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) for a better knowledge to insert data into BigQuery.